# Dating the Biblical Birth of Jesus

Tags: nativity

Is Yeshua's Biblical birth related to the 25th of December (Kislev)?

The Bible appears to set the timeline for Christmas in [Luke 1:5] : when Zechariah the father of John the Baptist served as priest in the temple of YHVH (in the ' order of Abijah' ). The ' order of Abijah ' refers to the division of temple priests who led services on Sabbath during the month of July ('Tammuz').  This order of priests was decided by King David in [1 Chronicles 24:10].  [ This means Zechariah conceives John the Baptist with his wife Elizabeth during the month of July. ]

- During the sixth month of Elizabeth's pregnancy (January) stated in [Luke 1:26] Mary is visited by Gabriel and concieves "Yeshua" whose name means 'YHVH is Salvation' .

- Nine months later on the 15th of Tishri (October) during the Festival of Tabernacles, does Mary deliver the messiah [Luke 2:4-7] in a manger (Tabernacle/Booth) in Bethlehem fulfilling the prophecies of [Micah 5] and [Leviticus 23]?

[Does the Bible ever mention December 25th?]

The Bible only mentions December 25 *once - regarding the Festival of Chanukah (Dedication) in [1 Maccabees 4].

Although Yeshua of Nazareth celebrated Chanukah in [John 10], can the Bible provide textual evidence linking the birth date of Yeshua of Nazareth to the 25th of December (Kislev) - instead of the 15th of Tishri?

Comment: No, it isn't. December 25th comes nine months after March 25th. Nissan is the beginning of months. Adam, then, was created on the sixth day of this month. (Alternately, on the sixth of Tishri; hence the conception of John the Baptist on September 23rd). More on this topic [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/revisions/46700/3).

Comment: The date of Jesus' birth is unknown.  All we know is that He was born before Herod's death in April 4 BC while shepherds still camped in the fields - probably before about Oct/Nov 5 BC and after the census was announced in 8 BC.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider:

The best months to visit Tel Aviv are April, May, June, September and October.

In the Galilee (northern Israel), rainfall in winter can even be heavy, with occasional snowfall in mountainous regions.

And Ezra 3:1-4, John 2:19-21.

https://thepointsguy.com/guide/best-times-to-visit-israel/